# How to force Woocommerce to use full sized images ONLY on category lists?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

For this page:
https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/

You can see that the category list at the top of the page's images are blurry. This is because I am using CSS to increase their size (only slightly though, I'm not sure why their sizes are so much smaller than what I have) and I assume this occurs after the page loads the thumbnail images.

I want this menu ONLY to use full sized images. I've found lots of solutions, but none work or are good so far.
Adding a PHP line to scale all images isn't what I'm after.
I assume the easiest would be to find the code responsible for making that category list and editing the line where it gets the image, but no matter where I look, I can't seem to find any code like that.

Comment: Your first two categories, Plants and Shrimp, have img elements with a full `srcset`, providing image variants up to sizes such as 2048x1536. The third one, Snails, only has an img element with one direct `src` URL, and that one is for an image of size 260x195. Unless anything was explicitly done to _force_ such a difference within the template, I think the most logical explanation is probably that you simply did not upload a large enough image for Snails to begin with ...?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for checking; The first two categories however are also showing lower quality images, not just the third. Even if this is the case it is irrelevant, all the images are smaller than they should be, and if the snail image is still too small ill upload a larger image after fixing the issue.

Comment: Checking this in an about 1600 px wide browser window in Chrome, DOM inspector  shows me that the actual image source it is using for the first category, Plants, is https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/20170206_224529-scaled-600x450.jpg, and it gets displayed with a width of 545 pixels. If what that results in isn't not good enough for you - then you will have to look into how you can manipulate what image sizes WP outputs in the srcset attribute.

Comment: @CBroe That should be large enough but you can see the image looks blurry right? If you open that link its the same size but sharp, but when displayed on the page its completely blurry. Are you saying that its a different issue then? Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: _"If you open that link its the same size"_ - you are talking about the image URL I last mentioned? Now, that won't be in the same size then, when you open it in a new browser tab - then it will show at it's actual size, 600x450, whereas in your site it gets scaled down to 545 pixels in width. Depending on image detail etc., of course it can get a bit blurrier in that process.

Comment: You could try and see if https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering gets you anywhere - though I guess you would need `optimizeQuality`, which has bad browser support. Other than that, I suppose you could only try and manipulate the image sizes WP creates, so that you actually use 545px instead of 600, so that the browser doesn't have to scale the image itself by that factor of 0.90833333333...

Comment: @CBroe, Playing around with it in css that can't be the issue: It can't be using the 600x size image.
When I set object-fit: none; it shows what size they actually are, (I need to send a screenshot somehow) but its much smaller, its using the 260x size I think. Its not the scale thats the issue. 
Its because I use object-fit: cover, but the origional image is much smaller that it is covering.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean here. Checking which image size actually gets loaded for the Plants category, by filtering the requests in the network panel for `20170206_224529` clearly shows that the `20170206_224529-scaled-600x450.jpg` version gets requested at a window width of about 1600px, and none of the other sizes.

Comment: @CBroe Think I found the issue, in the html there is the line: "sizes=(max-width: 260px) 100vw, 260px"... with srcset that means that it resizes the image to 260px max right? ...! Wait, doing the same thing you did, when I check my network pannel, it fetches the 260px size image... Why is it different for you? What browser are you using?

Comment: A Chromium-based one (Vivaldi), on Mac.

Comment: Interesting, so looks like this might be a browser-specific issue then? The image that loads for me is 260px width. I'll post another Q for now since this has changed quite a bit.

Comment: @CBroe you can see what's happening on my pc here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111691/wordpress-srcset-and-size-uses-too-small-image-in-windows-browsers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/sizes#selecting_an_image_to_fit_window_width: _"How exactly the images are used may depend upon the browser and what the pixel density of the user's display is."_ - could be that's the significant difference here, retina display on my Mac where I am looking at this, vs - non-retina on your end ...?

Comment: My screen is fullHD, its strange that that would matter but maybe? Either way its still an issue though. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation and help from comments, it looks like the issue is that for some reason my srcset size is set to 260px max which is limiting the image. Will be making a second question for that since its a different issue.