# Wordpress, srcset and size uses too small image in windows browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

In the following site: https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/

On a chrome browser, the images in the category list are loading 260px size when their size should be 600px (545px render).

This apparently is not consistent on all browsers, some of them rendering 600px correctly. Below is attatched an image of what occurs on Chrome for me.

I am pretty stumped on what the issue can be here. Any ideas?

[image: htms]

Answer (score 0):

I have added few changes and it is working fine. Please check.

```html
<img src="https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-300x225.jpg" alt="Shrimp" srcset="https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-2048x1536.jpg 2048w, https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-1536x1152.jpg 1536w, https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-1024x768.jpg 1024w, https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-768x576.jpg 768w, https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-600x450.jpg 600w, https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-300x225.jpg 300w, https://aquariumplantsonline.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Red-Cherry-Shrimp-Zoomed-edge-260x195.jpg 260w" sizes="(max-width: 261px) 260px, (max-width: 320px) 300px, (max-width: 601px) 600px, (max-width: 769px) 768x, (max-width: 1025px) 1024x, (max-width: 1537px) 1536x, (max-width: 2049px) 2048x">
```

Comment: So how do I edit this code in Wordpress? I would have to edit the code snippet for the category display? Where is that? Or am I able to use css for this?

Comment: Here is the official document which tells several ways to do that. https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/responsive-images/#customizing-responsive-image-markup

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with php before so that documentation does not make sense. Are you able to provide a step by step process on how to include that into the website? The docs seems to describe making your own custom function, that doesn't seem to be what I want to do?